# How to define a function interface that allows any number of arguments and 1 required argument?

Tags: python, mypy

How can I get rid of this mypy error?

```
class TestListener(Protocol):
    def __call__(self, command: str, *args: tuple[Any, ...],) -> Any:
        ...


def test(listener: TestListener):
    ...


def listener1(command: str, test: int):
    ...

def listener2(command: str):
    ...

def listener3(command: str, *args):
    ...

test(listener1) # error: Argument 1 to "test" has incompatible type "Callable[[str, int], Any]"; expected "TestListener"
test(listener2) # error: Argument 1 to "test" has incompatible type "Callable[[str], Any]"; expected "TestListener"
test(listener3) # this works
```

I would like all 3 to work.

Comment: Something like [this](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=master&python=3.11&flags=strict&gist=b3ce59f41ba4537f376f108966108911)?